# MFC How to change link text color of CLinkCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc

From this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd54bd30-e21f-4dc7-a77f-88de02c63f72/changing-link-label-color-for-syslink?forum=vcgeneral), I have set up the code by putting in the `OnInitDialog` event:

```
LITEM* pItem = new LITEM;

pItem->iLink = 0; // Url index is 0    

//LIF_ITEMINDEX is required for iLink, LIF_STATE is required for modifing state
pItem->mask = LIF_ITEMINDEX | LIF_STATE;

//using LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS state
pItem->state = LIS_ENABLED | LIS_FOCUSED | LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS;
pItem->stateMask = LIS_ENABLED | LIS_FOCUSED | LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS;

// Send the LM_SETITEM MESSAGE with pItem
HWND m_hWnd=nil; GetDlgItem(IDC_lbstackoverflow, &m_hWnd);
```

And from `OnCtrlColor` event:

```
pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
pDC->SetBkColor(normal);
pDC->SetDCBrushColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
```

After the code runs, my result is:

[image]

If I click on it, now it works:

[image]

But, how I can change text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be setting the control state correctly.

Please try the MFC way (it works for me). Add to your dialog class:

```
CLinkCtrl syslink;
```

Connect it to the resource ID of your link:

```
void CMFCApplication4Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SYSLINK1, syslink);
}
```

and in `OnInitDialog` add this:

```
syslink.SetItemState(0, LIS_ENABLED | LIS_FOCUSED | LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS, 
    LIS_ENABLED | LIS_FOCUSED | LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS);
```

I see red link with your code in `OnCtlColor`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I tried change CTLCOLOR_STATIC instead of WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC and now, it worked.